# What is the purpose of \$C_E\$ in this circuit?

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, bypass-capacitor

I understand it acts like a filter for \$R_E\$, but what is the point?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In DC analysis, capacitors are taken as open-circuit. In small signal low or medium frequency AC analysis, capacitors are taken as short-circuit.

So, as @nidhin explained, C<sub>E</sub> shorts R<sub>E</sub> in AC.

What does this bring? R<sub>E</sub> provides thermal stability so that the DC operation point (i.e. bias) does not change. Without C<sub>E</sub>, small signal voltage gain would be \$A_V = -R_C / (r_e + R_E)\$, where \$r_e = 26mV/I_{C-bias}\$. Since R<sub>E</sub> is shorted by a sufficiently large capacitor, C<sub>E</sub>, voltage gain will be \$A_V = R_C/r_e\$.

RESULTS:

- DC thermal stability remains.
- Voltage gain increased.
- Gain becomes transistor-dependent which we mostly don't want.

Comment: Excellent answer thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

\$R_E\$ provides negative feedback to improve the bias stability. But this negative feedback will reduce the signal gain also. So a capacitor \$C_E\$ is applied in parallel so that only the DC component experiences the negative feedback and the AC signal is 'bypassed' via \$C_E\$